# what does web preference mean in electron js and why nodeIntegration is set to false default?

Tags: electron

I am following the electron Js docs : https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app
and its given there,

```
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

but I am unable to find what it does mean actually, afaik it is something using node in other modules, but since electron uses chromium and nodejs ! why does we need to set it false, I read that its regarding the security!

My question is :-

1. What does `webPreferences` mean anyway?
2. Why we use it ?
3. Why is `nodeIntegration: false` by default ? Where we should put it true and where we should put it false?

Thanks for everyone answer and support

Answer (score 3):

`webPreferences` is described in Electron's documentation pages:

> https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window
>
> `webPreferences Object` (optional) - Settings of web page's features.

The `nodeIntegration` property is described as:

> Whether node integration is enabled. Default is `false`.

When `nodeIntegration: true` it causes NodeJS's features to be accessible directly from your page's script context, such as NodeJS's implementation of `module`, `exports`, and `require`. This is incompatible with jQuery, RequireJS, Meteor and AngularJS because they define their own versions of `module`, `exports`, or `require`. So setting `nodeIntegration: false` will prevent that conflict.

This is described in the Electron FAQ: https://electronjs.org/docs/faq

Because Electron applications *could* allow users to run arbitrary JavaScript - or have vulnerabilities that allow arbitrary JavaScript to run, it means you probably don't want to expose NodeJS's internal JS API to the Electron application (because then a malicious script could mess around with the user's local filesystem, start new processes, etc) so it's best to keep `nodeIntegration: false` unless you know what you're doing. Note that `nodeIntegration: false` is the default.

Comment: so, if I am setting ```nodeIntegration : true``` I can use node in renderer process! else I wont be able to.

Comment: @sudiptdabral Yes

Comment: if i leave `noteIntegration` as `false`, does this mean i wont have access to modules like `path`, `url`, and other node modules within my renderer script?

Comment: A bit late, but you can expose those modules using preload.js, see the official electron documentation